# Using Swift pull data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Firebase looks like

Firebase ScreenShot

[image]

This is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var sum = 0
    var counter = 0
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("WaterAdded").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let totalwateradded = snapshot.value as? [Int]{
            while counter < (totalwateradded.count) {
                var newValue = totalwateradded[counter]
                sum += newValue
            }
        self.totalAdded.text = "\(sum)"
        }
    })
}
```

I want to grab all the number in Firebase and display the sum. But it display nothing.

Comment: I notice a couple of things: First, it looks like the code casts the snapshot.value to an array of integers, which it should just cast to an integer. Plus, the values are being stored as strings instead of integers. Also what is `totalwateradded`? If it has no initial contents, the code inside the `while` loop will never be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly cast snapshot.value to [Int], instead if you want to get all objects in your node you should use

```
 let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("WaterAdded").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let water = snapshot.value as? String{
          guard let waterAmount = Int(water) else{return}
          sum += waterAmount

        }
    })
```

that while loop is not needed as this will give you all the values in the database.

**Edit**

In the database you can use Strings and Ints to store numbers. You store them as Strings. If you load them in Swift you have to conditionally cast the value to String (as? String). The problem, however is that you can not do any arithmetic operations on strings so using the Int(water) statement you can convert it to Int. This operation can give an integer from a string if it contains a number, but it can also fail (e.g. Int("two")) and therefore we use guard let to make sure we only proceed to the next line if it can successfully convert to an Int. Afterwards we just add the int value to sum and done.

Comment: Are you sure that WaterAdded is a direct child of the root reference? Are you printing sum to the console?

Comment: Yea, and I even tried to put a  print("helloworld") at end to test it. Its not showing neither.

Comment: Ah, ok I got it:) Your values are in String format so I'll update my answer.

Comment: i try to change to  if let water = snapshot.value as? String print(totalwateradded)  and its work, but it print out as string one by one.

Comment: Your new answer work perfect. Can you explain to me a little bit?

Comment: I added explanation. If this answers your question please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
if let snap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary [Sting: Any], let totalWaterAdded = 
snap["\(yourDictionaryKey)"] as? Int{
//enter your code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that reads the node, sums the values and print it to console.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("WaterAdded")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    var x = 0
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let val = (child as! DataSnapshot).value as! Int
        x = x +  val
    }
    print("sum: \(x)")
})
```

We're using observeSingleEvent of .value in this case as there's really no reason for firebase to iterate over each child when we can do it a lot faster in code. Also, we don't need to be notified of childAdded events.

Tossing a guard statement in the mix may be a good idea but as long as you are sure the values will only be Int's, it's good to go as is.

Tested with the following structure

```
WaterAdded
   a: 0
   b: 1
   c: 2
   d: 3
```

and the output is

```
6
```

Comment: It crash, said that "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on second line of your code

Comment: @LOTR94 Correct. As I mentioned if you are SURE the values will only be Int's then it's good to go. If you have something else, you need a guard in there to catch it. Code is tested and works, and I am not using any optional values on the second line. Remember to replace self.ref with *your* Firebase root reference.